# Robot-Framework: how to get list from keyword and verify items

Tags: python, robotframework

So in my test i have `keyword` that return list:

```
@{channels}=        Get Channels
```

For example the return list is `['1', '4', '11']`

And i want to loop over this list and verify that 1, 4 and 11 exist at that list.

This is what i have try:

```
FOR     ${ELEMENT}        IN      @{channels}
            Log     ${ELEMENT}
            List Should Contain Sub List  @{channels}  ${ELEMENT}
END
```

And i received this `error`:

> TypeError: Expected argument 1 to be a list or list-like, got string
> instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in how you use the first variable. With the decorators you only tell robot framework how to work with the variables. You can read more about list variables and decorators
[here.](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variable)

```
${channels}=        Get Channels
```

just save the result as is($) using List Should Contain Value should match better since in your ${ELEMENT} there is no sublist.

```
FOR     ${ELEMENT}        IN      @{channels}
            Log     ${ELEMENT}
            List Should Contain Value    ${channels}    ${ELEMENT}
END
```

Comment: So i only changed @{channels}= to ${channels}= and again:TypeError: Expected argument 1 to be a list or list-like, got string instead.

Comment: that is strange. Can you use "Log" keyword and have a look at the ${cahnnels}?

Comment: ${cahnnels}: ['1', '6', '11']

Comment: i see. the error is on keyword "List Should Contain Sub List"? You should also use the $ decorator in this keyword. I must admit i didnt look  so far

Comment: Yes, The keyword "List Should Contain Sub List"

Comment: Maybe i can use another keyword to verify my list ?

Comment: Use the $ decorator there as well. https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Lists%20Should%20Be%20Equal

Comment: What decorator ?

Comment: List Should Contain Sub List  ${channels}  ${ELEMENT}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228894/discussion-between-jiri-janous-and-user1860934).